# UITest Query for UIImage inside of a UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview, xcode-ui-testing

I am writing a UI test in Swift against an iOS app that contains a `UITableView` with a custom `UITableViewCell` loaded from a nib. The cell contains a `UIImageView` and a `UILabel`.

When the table is rendered, there is no `XCUIElementQuery` that finds the image element. How can you get access to the ImageView during the UI Test to know the source of the image that was specified in the icon field?

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var name: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var icon: UIImageView!
}
```

The image does not appear in `app.images`, `app.tables.cells.images` or `app.tables.cells.otherElements`. It seems like the image icons are nowhere to be found in the UI hierarchy.

Comment: Is your UITableViewCell set to be an accessible element? If it is, that might result in the UI hierarchy terminating there. Containers should not be accessible, accessible elements cannot contain other accessible elements.

Comment: Accessibility is not enabled for the cell and it is possible to see the label inside the cell, just not the image.

Comment: If you set accessible identifier to imageView , you can find image like this "app.tables.cells.images["identifier"]"  and if you want specific cell's icon of index then can use "app.tables.cells.elementBoundByIndex(index).images["identifier"]", but you can't find image file name in hierarchy

Comment: If you want to check the resource name of an image depending on some data, you should use a unit test, not a UI test.

Answer (score 4):

It's late, but for other users...

I solved it as follows:

1. Add accessibilityIdentifier for table.

`self.tableView.accessibilityIdentifier = "ExampleTableView"`

2. Set imageView isAccessibilityElement to true !!!

**`cell.icon.isAccessibilityElement = true`**

3. Image name in variable and set accessibilityLabel's image with variable name.

`let imageName = "example_image"`

`cell.icon.accessibilityIdentifier = "ExampleTableViewCellIcon"`

`cell.icon.accessibilityLabel = imageName`

`cell.icon.image = UIImage(named: imageName)!`

4. Test

`XCTAssert(app.tables["ExampleTableView"].cells.element(boundBy: 0).images[ExampleTableViewCellIcon].label == "example_image")`

Answer (score 1):

The path of the image is not accessible in UI Testing. The framework sees the app as a user does, why would someone care about the filename of a check mark?

**Update**: To relate the user interface / accessibility to your different icons, you can set accessibility identifiers when setting the image.

```
MyCell().icon?.accessibilityIdentifier = "check"
```

Comment: The resource name of the icon can be different depending on the data in that cell row.

Comment: You can change the accessibility identifier of the image view. See my edit.